# Why Is Knex.js Failing on Password Authentication When My Database Has No Password?

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I'm trying to connect to my database using Knex like so:

```
const client = knex({
  client: 'postgresql',
  connection: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'me',
    database: 'my_db'
  }
});
client('some_table').then(console.log);
```

When I created the database (using `createdb my_db` at the command line) I set no password.  At the command line I can run `psql -d my_db` and it works just fine.

However, when I try to use Knex, I get an error:

> Unhandled rejection error: password authentication failed for user "me"

This happens whether I set a `null` password, an empty string (`''`) password, or leave the field off of the configuration entirely.

Can anyone explain why Knex insists on failing password authentication ... when there is no password (and when I can connect without one at the command line just fine)?

Comment: Thanks, but is it truly impossible to use Knex without a password on your user/db?  That seems wrong.

Comment: Right, but I'm trying to understand A) what does a *user* password have to do with this: isn't the *database* password what's relevant? ... and then B) whatever password it is, shouldn't I be able to connect without one? I can at the command line with `psql`, so why can't Knex?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try using a url instead. But still ... it just seems like I'm missing something obvious, because it seems like it MUST be possible for Knex to connect without a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not permit login based on the presence/absence of a password.  Rather, all login authentication is handled via `pg_hba.conf`.  In your particular case--creating the `me` user without a password (or using `null` or `''`, as you would describe it)--the absence of the password doesn't necessarily allow your user to log in.  In fact, setting no password will not allow that user to log in unless `pg_hba.conf` was set to some password-less setting (i.e., `peer` or `trust`).

If you want password-less login for the `me` user (I assume for testing/development purposes, as having password-less login is not good security practice in production), you could simply set `trust`-level authentication in `pg_hba.conf`:

```
#conn_origin  database  user  ip_mask   auth_method
host          all       me    0.0.0.0/0 trust
```

The more secure method of implementing password-less authentication would be to use a `.pgpass` file or set the `PGPASSWORD` environment variable.  Seeing that you are trying to use knex.js, you may be better off with tweaking `pg_hba.conf` as above.  Again, I don't know what your intentions are, but please be safe out there ;)

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](https://www.enterprisedb.com)